# On password change will user have to re-authenticate on 'Salesforce for Outlook', 'Chatter Desktop', 'Chatter Mobile'?

Tags: single-sign-on

We have enabled Delegated Authentication in our salesforce org. End users are using various desktop and mobile clients(Salesforce for Outlook, Chatter Desktop, Chatter Mobile etc) to access salesforce.

If users change their SSO password, will they have to re-login on the client applications using the new password?

If NO, then are we saying that the end uses will have to authenticate themselves only ONCE to use a client application. And the client application will continue using the same session-Id for all the future logins.

Thanks,

Comment: I installed 'Salesforce for Outlook', 'Chatter Desktop', 'Chatter Mobile' and logged-in on all these clients using my developer org credentials(not sso enabled). Now I changed my salesforce password and re-stared my laptop and mobile to check whether these clients prompt to enter new password, but all the clients started working without entering new password.  Can somebody tell me till how long these client application wont prompt for new password?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to change the password because those applications have used OAuth to obtain a token that authorises them.

Changing passwords will not effect them, The tokens are perpetual until revoked by the client or on the server by the user or an admin (or Freeze/Deactivate the user).

See this article:  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_request_manage.htm&language=en

Comment: The tokens are perpetual until revoked by the client or on the server by the user or an admin. You should probably mention that.